# How can I elegantly check if any field has a longer value between two objects in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, syntactic-sugar

Consider:

```
item1 = {a:[1], b:[2], c:[3]}
item2 = {a:[1], b:[2], c:[3,4]}
```

I can write a lengthy `for` loop to do the job, but I am wondering: Is there an elegant way to check if any field has a length value (in the above example, `item2`'s `c` is longer than `item1`'s `c`) between two objects in JavaScript?

Comment: How is it lengthy? Seems pretty straight forward loop with a check.

Comment: Can you add a nice example input with a couple of "lengthy" fields/elements? Plus it would be nice to add your current loop so we can see what you mean.

Comment: yea but am just wondering if things like .map(), .forEach() can lead to a one line solution

Comment: Do you also need to know which keys are longer? If you just want to know if `item2` has some keys longer than `item1` then CertainPerformance's answer should cover you.

Comment: no the purpose was to monitor is there a change or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a pretty simple iteration over the `Object.entries` of one of the objects and doesn't seem lengthy at all:

```js
// Assuming that both objects will contain the same keys:
const item1 = {a:[1], b:[2], c:[3]};
const item2 = {a:[1], b:[2], c:[3,4]};

const anyInItem2Bigger = Object.entries(item1)
  .some(([key, val1]) => item2[key].length > val1.length);
console.log(anyInItem2Bigger);
```

Or, to golf it more, but make it less readable, you can [destructure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_(computer_science)#Parallel_assignment) the `length` property of the `val1` immediately:

```js
// Assuming that both objects will contain the same keys:
const item1 = {a:[1], b:[2], c:[3]};
const item2 = {a:[1], b:[2], c:[3,4]};

const anyInItem2Bigger = Object.entries(item1)
  .some(([key, { length }]) => item2[key].length > length);
console.log(anyInItem2Bigger);
```

Comment: I like looping over `Object.keys` a bit more, allows for `item2[key].length > item1[key].length` in the callback which looks a tiny bit cleaner to me (though longer). Nice answer anyway, just my 0.02.

Answer (score 4):

This is just an alternative to [CertainPerformance's great solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54564726/how-can-i-elegantly-check-if-any-field-has-a-longer-value-between-two-objects-in/54564759#54564759), as someone suggested I posted it into another answer.

It simply uses [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) instead of [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), and might look a tiny bit cleaner even though it's 99% the same:

```js
const item1 = {a:[1], b:[2], c:[3]};
const item2 = {a:[1], b:[2], c:[3,4]};

const anyInItem2Bigger = Object.keys(item1)
  .some(key => item2[key].length > item1[key].length);
```

To add something a bit more valuable, if you need retrieve the actual list of keys that have longer items, you could make use of [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
const item1 = {a:[1], b:[2], c:[3]};
const item2 = {a:[1], b:[2], c:[3,4]};

const longerKeysInItem2 = Object.keys(item1)
  .reduce((lk, key) => item2[key].length > item1[key].length ? [...lk, ...[key]] : lk, []);

console.log(longerKeysInItem2);
```

Comment: +1 I'll just add a small note to the question OP which applies to both answers: These solutions might not give expected results if a key doesn't contain an Array. I think it's out of scope for the answers to add checks for edge cases but it's worth noting in case they are blindly copy/pasted to production code.

Comment: @NikKyriakides Right, this assumes the keys are the exact same in both items and all values are arrays. It should only be used "as is" if these things are certain.